# Output mistake in array

Tags: c, arrays, char, string-matching, brute-force

```
int BruteForceStringMatch(char Text[], char Pattern[]){

    int TextSize = sizeof(Text) / sizeof(Text[0]); //get size of arrays
    int PatternSize = sizeof(Pattern) / sizeof(Pattern[0]);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i++; i < TextSize - PatternSize){
        int j = 0;
        while(j < PatternSize && Pattern[j] == Text[i + j]){
            j = j + 1;
        }
        if(j = PatternSize){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    char x [] = "if" ;
    char y [] = "aslifee";

    int c = BruteForceStringMatch(y,x);
    printf("%d ",c);

    getchar();       
}
```

Hi everyone, I want to match text and pattern by using BruteForceStringMatch function but I get output -1 from computer. Here I should get 3 (because fourth element is matching) but why am I getting -1 which means there is no matching?

Comment: `for(i=0;i++;i<TextSize-PatternSize){`?????

Comment: What is this `for` loop supposed to do?

Comment: formatting for the sake of the reader please

Comment: Friends, This function is about brute force string match, brute force string match algorithm like these. This algorithm look one-by-one to match text and pattern.

Comment: No user3121..... This algorithm is true. I controlled.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is wrong:

```
int TextSize = sizeof(Text)/sizeof(Text[0]); //get size of arrays
```

This does *not* give you the size of the array, because C passes arrays to functions as if they were pointers. The size of the array is stripped from it, so `sizeof` returns the size of the pointer.

Use `strlen` instead:

```
int TextSize = strlen(Text);
```

Same goes for the pattern size.

Note: I assume that you are doing this as a learning exercise, because C standard library supplies a [function for finding strings within strings.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/)

Comment: It's my project assignment, We have to do like these. But I tried, it doesn't change, still output is -1.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I fixed. I made a basic mistake, I couldn't care. For loop should be like : for(i = 0; i <= TextSize - PatternSize; i++)